# TypeError: 'DType' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following code throws a `TypeError`

```
import tensorflow as tf
h=tf.int32(6)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'DType' object is not callable
```

Why?

Comment: You are using `()` on an object that can't be called. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tf.int32` object is not a constructor. If you want to create a tensor of type `tf.int32` with value `6`, you should use [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), as follows:

```
h = tf.constant(6, dtype=tf.int32)
```